# Minimum A/C Voltage to drive 12V regulator

Tags: transformer, linear-regulator

Noob here.  I have a 28V CT transformer.  I want to use it to drive a 7812 and 7912 regulators. The data sheets says min. input voltage is 14.8V.  How do I calculate what the unregulated DC voltage from a bridge rectifier would be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformer and two half bridges will give you about

+/-(\$\sqrt{2}\times\$14)-1~= 19VDC from 14+14VAC RMS.

The 1V is to account for the diode drop.

That gives you a bit of margin for ripple on the capacitor and mains voltage tolerance.

Note that the transformer voltage may be significantly higher with a light load compared to full rated load for the transformer- not a problem with max input voltage of the regulators, but power dissipation could become an issue in some cases.